# File does not exist in database - SQL Server Snapshot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to create a database snapshot with SQL Server 2008 R2 using the following T-SQL code.

```
CREATE DATABASE SNAP_myDB_0900
ON
 (NAME = myDB, FILENAME = 'C:\myDB_0900.SNAP')
AS SNAPSHOT OF myDB
```

I get the following error:

> The file 'myDB' does not exist in database 'myDB'

This code works with other databases in the same instance but not this one. I have double checked the file name and it is correct.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Does the server have access to the direct C:\ that the database lives on?  The C:\ on your computer is not the same C:\ referenced in the statement.

Comment: @TTeeple the server does have access, as this code works with other databases on the server instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Verify the database file name that you are trying to create the snapshot based off of:

```
select name, physical_name
from myDB.sys.database_files;
```

The `NAME` you give you snapshot file(s) needs to match the source database file name.

In other words, if `myDB`'s data file has a name of `datafile1`, then you will have to use `... NAME = 'datafile1' ...` when creating your snapshot.

Comment: I was using the physical_name that resulted in the error, it is working now with the name in the "name" column. Thanks much!